# Exception Error in creating an instance of RandomDataImpl

Tags: java, classpath, javac

I am getting this exception error at

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/apache/commons/math3/random/RandomDataImpl
```

at this line of code:

```
randomData_ = new RandomDataImpl();
```

and this is how the class is imported in the code :

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.random.RandomDataImpl;
```

i have added all of the math common classes to the classpath while running the code. any ideas whats going on ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not set the appropriate classpath.
You can set it as follows:

```
java -classpath lib/*.jar:. mypackage.MyClass
```

Try that and I am sure it will work.

If you are using maven, then read [this article](http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2009/11/3-ways-to-run-java-main-from-maven/)

You can also check your current classpath with:

```
System.getProperty("java.class.path")
```

Just write simple app printing this property out and run it just as you run an app with which you are having problems.

Comment: I'm not sure if i fully understood what you mean, but this is how I've been doing it : java -Xmx256m -classpath /Users/../code/library:/Users/../code/commons-cli-1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/Users/../code/commons-math-2.2/commons-math-2.2.jar:/Users/../code/common-math3-3.1.1/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/Users/../code/common-math3-3.2/commons-math3-3.2.jar WriteLandmark

Comment: do you mean these commons?  : code/common-math3‌​-3.2/commons-math3-3.2.jar